# How to push_back() a member variable of a struct

Tags: c++, variables, vector, struct

I have a struct

```
struct Node
{
    string Name;
    vector<float> probs;
    vector<Node*> connections;
};
```

and I have a `vector` of strings called Input each line is as follows

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

and I want to `.push_back()` into `connections` if i find a 1

I used the following

```
  int N=5;
  Node Tables[N];

  for (int i = 0; i < N*2-1; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < N*2-1; ++j)
    {
      if (Input[i][j] == '1')
      {
        Tables[i].connections.push_back(Tables[j]);
      }
    }
  }
```

and I get this error when compiling

```
main.cpp:128:31: error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
        Tables[i].connections.push_back(Tables[j]);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `connections` is a vector of *pointers* to `Node`, while `Tables[j]` is a `Node` *object* (and not a pointer).

Comment: yes i see i needed ```Tables[i].connections.push_back(&Tables[j]);```

Comment: Aside: `i < N*2-1` is a very suspicious loop boundary

Comment: yes @Caleth that caused an issued i resolved it by getting rid of all the spaces in the vector so it was a 5x5

Answer (score 0):

Here in while the declaration of the structure, you declare a vector of Node(pointer) inside that structure.
As a vector of pointers, you can only push_back() any Node type element **address**.
If you only modify the code as like :  `Tables[i].connections.push_back(&Tables[j]);`
You can resolve that error.